# Penalized cumulative sum in r

Tags: r, panel, cumulative-sum

I need to calculate a penalized cumulative sum.

Individuals "A", "B" and "C" were supposed to get tested every other year. Every time they get tested, they accumulate 1 point. However, when they miss a test, their cumulative score gets deducted in 1.

I have the following code:

```
data.frame(year = rep(1990:1995, 3), person.id = c(rep("A", 6), rep("B", 6), rep("C", 6)),   needs.testing = rep(c("Yes", "No"), 9), test.compliance = c(c(1,0,1,0,1,0), c(1,0,1,0,0,0), c(1,0,0,0,0,0)), penalized.compliance.cum.sum = c(c(1,1,2,2,3,3), c(1,1,2,2,1,1), c(1,1,0,0,-1,-1)))
```

...which gives the following:

```
  year person.id needs.testing test.compliance penalized.compliance.cum.sum
1  1990         A           Yes               1                            1
2  1991         A            No               0                            1
3  1992         A           Yes               1                            2
4  1993         A            No               0                            2
5  1994         A           Yes               1                            3
6  1995         A            No               0                            3
7  1990         B           Yes               1                            1
8  1991         B            No               0                            1
9  1992         B           Yes               1                            2
10 1993         B            No               0                            2
11 1994         B           Yes               0                            1
12 1995         B            No               0                            1
13 1990         C           Yes               1                            1
14 1991         C            No               0                            1
15 1992         C           Yes               0                            0
16 1993         C            No               0                            0
17 1994         C           Yes               0                           -1
18 1995         C            No               0                           -1
```

As it is evident, "A" fully complied. "B" somewhat complied (in year 1994 he's supposed to get tested, but he missed the test, and consequently his cumulative sum gets deducted from 2 to 1). Finally, "C" complies just once (in year 1990, and every time she needs to get tested, she misses the test).

What I need is some code to get the "penalized.compliance.cum.sum" variable.

**Please note**:

1. Tests are every other year.
2. The "penalized.compliance.cum.sum" variable keeps adding the previous score.
3. But starts deducting only if the individual **misses the test on the testing year** (denoted in the "needs.testing" variable).

- For instance, individual "C" complies in year 1990. In 1991 she doesn't need to get tested, and hence keeps her score of 1. Then, she misses the 1992 test, and 1 is subtracted from her cumulative score, getting a score of 0 in 1992. Then she keeps missing test getting a -1 at the end of the study.

- Also, I need to assign different penalties (i.e. different numbers). In this example, it's just 1. However, I need to be able to penalize using other numbers such as 0.5, 0.1, and others.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(person.id) %>%
   mutate(res = cumsum(case_when(needs.testing == "Yes" ~ 1- 2 *(test.compliance < 1), TRUE ~ 0)))
```

Answer (score 2):

### base R

```r
do.call(rbind, by(dat, dat$person.id,
                  function(z) transform(z, res = cumsum(ifelse(needs.testing == "Yes", 1-2*(test.compliance < 1), 0))) 
))
#      year person.id needs.testing test.compliance penalized.compliance.cum.sum res
# A.1  1990         A           Yes               1                            1   1
# A.2  1991         A            No               0                            1   1
# A.3  1992         A           Yes               1                            2   2
# A.4  1993         A            No               0                            2   2
# A.5  1994         A           Yes               1                            3   3
# A.6  1995         A            No               0                            3   3
# B.7  1990         B           Yes               1                            1   1
# B.8  1991         B            No               0                            1   1
# B.9  1992         B           Yes               1                            2   2
# B.10 1993         B            No               0                            2   2
# B.11 1994         B           Yes               0                            1   1
# B.12 1995         B            No               0                            1   1
# C.13 1990         C           Yes               1                            1   1
# C.14 1991         C            No               0                            1   1
# C.15 1992         C           Yes               0                            0   0
# C.16 1993         C            No               0                            0   0
# C.17 1994         C           Yes               0                           -1  -1
# C.18 1995         C            No               0                           -1  -1
```

`by` splits a frame up by the `INDICES` (`dat$person.id` here), where in the function `z` is the data for just that group. This allows us to operate on the data without fearing the person changing in a vector.

`by` returns a `list`, and the canonical base-R way to combine lists into a frame is either `rbind(a, b)` when only two frames, or `do.call(rbind, list(...))` when there may be more than two frames in the list.

The `1-2*(.)` is just a trick to waffle between +1 and -1 based on `test.compliance`.

This has the side-effect of potentially changing the order of the rows. For instance, if it were ordered first by `year` then `person.id`, then the `by`-group calculations will still be good, but the output will be grouped by `person.id` (and ordered by `year` within the group). Minor, but note it if you need order to be something.

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(person.id) %>%
  mutate(res = cumsum(if_else(needs.testing == "Yes", 1-2*(test.compliance < 1), 0))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
datDT <- as.data.table(dat)
datDT[, res := cumsum(fifelse(needs.testing == "Yes", 1-2*(test.compliance < 1), 0)), by = .(person.id)]
```

Answer (score 2):

This might do the trick for you?

```
df <- data.frame(year = rep(1990:1995, 3), person.id = c(rep("A", 6), rep("B", 6), rep("C", 6)),   needs.testing = rep(c("Yes", "No"), 9), test.compliance = c(c(1,0,1,0,1,0), c(1,0,1,0,0,0), c(1,0,0,0,0,0)), penalized.compliance.cum.sum = c(c(1,1,2,2,3,3), c(1,1,2,2,1,1), c(1,1,0,0,-1,-1)))

library("dplyr")

penalty <- -1
df %>% 
  group_by(person.id) %>% 
  mutate(cumsum = cumsum(ifelse(needs.testing == "Yes" & test.compliance == 0, penalty, test.compliance)))
## A tibble: 18 x 6
## Groups:   person.id [3]
#    year person.id needs.testing test.compliance penalized.compliance.cum.sum cumsum
#   <int> <chr>     <chr>                   <dbl>                        <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1  1990 A         Yes                         1                            1      1
# 2  1991 A         No                          0                            1      1
# 3  1992 A         Yes                         1                            2      2
# 4  1993 A         No                          0                            2      2
# 5  1994 A         Yes                         1                            3      3
# 6  1995 A         No                          0                            3      3
# 7  1990 B         Yes                         1                            1      1
# 8  1991 B         No                          0                            1      1
# 9  1992 B         Yes                         1                            2      2
#10  1993 B         No                          0                            2      2
#11  1994 B         Yes                         0                            1      1
#12  1995 B         No                          0                            1      1
#13  1990 C         Yes                         1                            1      1
#14  1991 C         No                          0                            1      1
#15  1992 C         Yes                         0                            0      0
#16  1993 C         No                          0                            0      0
#17  1994 C         Yes                         0                           -1     -1
#18  1995 C         No                          0                           -1     -1
```

You can then easily adjust the `penalty` variable to be whatever penalty you want.